# Zurb Foundation "th" thumbnail images within block grid unresponsive

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I just switched to ZURB Foundation 4 after much consideration (switching from Twitter Boostrap 3 RC1) and it's all good and fine mostly but I am concerned that I may already be running into some bugginess in it -- but the bugginess may be in my way I'm using it perhaps?

Basically, I am setting up a block grid within which are a series of images. Initially it works as expected: the images are automatically scaled into the width of their column, makes sense since they have `max-width:100%` and `height:auto`.

Now, when I add `class="th"` to each of the anchors for the images suddenly the images overflow their containers and are not size constrained at all but are the dimensions of the image file itself.

Inspecting this in Firefox I find that the only difference that could be causing this is that the `th` class has `line-height:0`. I'm somewhat new to all this stuff so I don't quite understand why they are setting the line-height to zero but as far as I can tell that's what is breaking everything in my usage. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Here's a code example:

```
<ul class="large-block-grid-4">
   <li>
      <a class="th" href="http://placehold.it/800x800.jpg">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/800x800.jpg" />
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

i.e. it overflows all over the place but if I just remove the `th` class, it's fine.

It looks like a bug to me but before I submitted it I wanted to make sure I wasn't an idiot and missing some important point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using just the default CSS (v4.3.1) and not SASS with the same issue. Only for me it occurred in IE 10/9 exclusively. In comparing the style sheet used for the docs and the one included in the download, I found one difference.

Add the below to the 'a.th' style:

```
max-width: 100%;
```

Comment: I reported the bug but they haven't even responded yet. Based on that I switched frameworks back to Bootstrap (and then decide to just write my own since I only needed a few features anyway) despite liking the design of Foundation better. Seems inexcusable to not get a response on a bug-report after 13 days for something that's supposed to be able to used on major commercial sites.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I verified the fix works with a codepen: http://cdpn.io/gJBtv . I will mark this as the correct answer because (1) it is by someone who verified the existence of this bug was not isolated to my usage and (2) it provided a fix -- though I wasn't so much looking for that.

Comment: Note that the bug was responded to on foundation and closed because they said "it's not supposed to be used on the anchor element but the img element"... which is the opposite of what their docs said. I alerted them that their doc specifically refers to it as "a.th" but they didn't ever reply or update their docs.

Answer (score 0):

it shouldn't overflow. http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/thumbnails.html

are you using sass or just working on top of their css?

Comment: sass. I created the project using compass. i don't see quite how using sass or not could make the difference but i suppose i could run a quick test to see whether it happened when linking directly to their distributed css file.